# Creating and removing folders in Tests

Tags: ruby, testing, testunit

I am trying to test a scenario where my app writes some files to a folder and that folder should then be removed after the test.

```
class TestDirectory < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @target = "some/path"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(@target)
  end

  def teardown
    FileUtils.rm_rf(@target)
  end

  test "remove directory" do
    #some tests
  end
end
```

But for some reason the folder does not get removed. I have also tried to set the secure option to false for FileUtils#rm_rf but that didn't help either. Neither the parent nor the target folder are world writable, which could be an issue according to the documentation. I am running on Mac OS X Lion.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing you should do is fire up `irb` and play with `FileUtils.rm_rf` until you understand how it works in different scenarios. After you verify how it is supposed to work, then you incorporate it into your test, and if it does not work then..at minimum you need to confirm `teardown` is getting called. It's just basic debugging practice: you have to narrow down your problem to the bare minimum to understand it. You're working with too many unknown variables at the same time right now (TestCase, teardown, permissions, rm_rf).

Comment: I have already done all of this.

Comment: Ok..great. And did rm_rf work in irb as expected?

Comment: Yes, everything worked as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'fileutils'

class TestDirectory < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @target = "/tmp/tmpfolder"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(@target)
  end

  def teardown
    FileUtils.rm_rf(@target)
  end

  def test_something
    assert 1 + 1 == 2
  end
end
```

Comment: The folder @target gets created during the test (via FileUtils.mkdir_p(@target)) but does not get removed in teardown.

Comment: It does for me. Can you run my simple script (assuming that you use Linux or something unixoid)? If you use Windows, the problem could be that you open a file withing this folder during the test and forgot to close it afterwards. You can't delete the parent folder then (but it should give you an error!)

Comment: I have tried it, it does not work for me. I am running on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: @mato Make sure your current working directory has not changed between `setup` and `teardown` if you're working with relative paths. Please debug with `puts FileUtils.pwd` in both setup and teardown.

Comment: @Mato: After running the script, there exists a directory `/tmp/tmpfolder`? I can hardly believe this.

Comment: @Niklas Yes, the folder still exists.

Comment: @Mato: That's strange. What about using `Dir.rmdir(@target)` instead?

Comment: @Niklas OK, Dir#rmdir works. The thing here is, that the directory has to be empty before it can be removed, but that is something I can live with. Thanks.

Comment: @Mato: Actually, if what you say is correct and
`FileUtils.mkdir_p("/tmp/tmpdir"); FileUtils.rm_rf("/tmp/tmpdir")` does not delete `tmp/tmpdir`, this is a Ruby bug and should be reported.

Comment: Did this ever get sorted out?